# How to load font awesome in fonts directory?

Tags: css, font-face, font-awesome

I can't load font awesome in fonts directory, in font awesome there is icon style like :

```
.fa-star:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
```

I want to get content: "\f005"; and put in my own style, but I think the directory fonts not load, how to load font awesome file in directory fonts?

I have try to add this code to my style:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and copy fonts folder.

here my style code:

```
.example li a:before {
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    content: "\f005";
}
```

here my directory structure

```
- assets
-- css
   mystyle.css
-- fonts
   FontAwesome.otf
   fontawesome-webfont.eot
   fontawesome-webfont.eot
   fontawesome-webfont.svg
   fontawesome-webfont.ttf
   fontawesome-webfont.woff
   fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

Comment: did you replace `../fonts` with `fonts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `font-family` for your custom class

```
.fa-star{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.fa-star:before {
    content: "\f005";
}
```